# Node.js pod isn't getting the preStop lifecycle signal from Kubernetes

Tags: node.js, kubernetes, hook, lifecycle

I want to shutdown Node.js gracefully, but it doesn't receive the preStop signal from Kubernetes.

```
process.on('preStop', handleShutdown);

function handleShutdown() {
  console.log("Pod will shut down in 30 seconds");
}
```

I current do not have a preStop lifecycle command in the .yaml because I couldn't find any way to get it to notify the Node.js worker

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

`preStop`
command will kill the container. Basically, it will kill your app process. If you set up only 'preStop', it does not work, unfortunately. Here is a sample POD, I played with minikube to test.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: lifecycle-demo
spec:
  containers:
  - name: lifecycle-demo-container
    image: nginx
    lifecycle:
      postStart:
        exec:
          command: ["/bin/sh", "-c", "echo Hello from the postStart handler > /usr/share/message"]
      preStop:
        exec:
          command: ["/bin/sh", "-c", "/bin/sleep 120"]
  terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 6000
```

I am telling to hold the kill for 120 second before killing it. If that does not happen, it will violently be killed after 6000 second.

For your case, `terminationGracePeriodSeconds` itself should be enough.